# Solvpnp() rvec to ros tf

Tags: ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
Im using python opencv solvepnp() solver to find the camera to object transformation for hand2eye calibration for my robot. It returns translation vector and rotation vector. But i want to convert rotation vector into ros tf. Ie, in my solvepnp() rvec have only x,y,z values are there. But in tf there is x,y,z,w values.**is ther any function to convert vector to quarternion in python??** Sorry, im very new to ros..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339382/solvpnp()-rvec-to-ros-tf/) by [Abhishekpg](https://answers.ros.org/users/50018/abhishekpg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2019-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I solved it using tf. using

from tf.transformations import quaternion_from_euler
3
4 if **name** == '**main**':
5
6   # RPY to convert: 90deg, 0, -90deg
7   q = quaternion_from_euler(1.5707, 0, -1.5707)

---

Originally posted by [Abhishekpg](https://answers.ros.org/users/50018/abhishekpg/) with karma: 195 on 2019-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0